# Когда стоит открывать соединение с базой данных?

Tags: php, база-данных, ооп, нагрузка

Вопрос по большой части про безопасность. Не могу определиться какой подход лучше для систем с постоянно активными более 100 пользователей:

1. В глобальном классе приложения сделать свойство `db`, который создает новый экземпляр класса `Database`. В его конструкторе сразу открывается соединение с базой. Все дальнейшие обращения  будет на уровне: `Application::$app->db->...`.
2. Создавать соединение (`new Database`) только в том месте, где надо.

В первом случае, меня беспокоит постоянно открытое соединение на пользователя, а во втором - большое количество соединение на работу с одной странице (до перезагрузки).

В первом случае, меньшее число соединений (единственное на пользователя), во втором - нет постоянно открытого соединения.

Подскажите, как лучше поступить и что из этого выбрать.

Comment: Если речь идет о сайте, мобильном приложении где работа быстрый request-response, то везде делают одно постоянное соединение. Да и с точки зрения безопасности, какая может быть в этом дыра? У вас приложение или работает с БД или нет. Безопасность в этом случае - это не пропустить ненужные данные в бд и работать через подготовленные запросы.

Comment: А если с точки зрения нагрузки? Что из этого более эффективно? Как я понял - первый вариант.

Comment: Верно. Нет смысла переподключения, в этом нагрузка. А то что лежит ресурс соединения - в этом нагрузки нет.

Comment: Если же речь идет о mysqli_connect  и mysqli_pconnect то это уже другой вопрос, в нем не подскажу.

Comment: Так не постоянно открыто же соединение, завершается вместе с запросом

Comment: В основе своей PHP приложению не важно как организовывать связь с БД, это дело демона БД. В MySQL это решается на уровне конфигурации пулов (connection pool), в большинстве аналогичных реляционных БД тоже. Единственное что нужно учитывать - это управление самой связью после того как она была открыта, чтобы она была доступна в течении жизни приложения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В некоторых распространенных фреймворках этот вопрос решается обычно достаточно просто - или использованием паттерна Singleton ("Одиночка") для запроса соединения с базой, или неявным созданием опять же одного объекта DAO для доступа к данным (которое остается скрытым "под капотом") при обращении к модели. Таким образом, и соединение не открывается пока не потребуется (а если не требуется - вообще не откроется), и соединение имеется в количестве адын штук на обрабатываемый HTTP-запрос, чего в подавляющем большинстве случаев хватает.

Примеры организации соединений с БД: [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database), [Yii](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/ru/start-databases).

Про Symfony писать не буду, там возможны различные разности - и Doctrine, и Eloquent, и черт в ступе, и лягушка в супе.

Таким образом, по практике использования можно сделать вывод - лучше всего создание соединения с БД "спрятать под капот" при обращении к высокоуровневым операциям, и "не светить" в таких местах, как контроллер. Хотя, если Вы (как и я) предпочитаете в некоторых случаях осуществлять "закат солнца вручную" и "после сборки обработать напильником" для достижения оптимальной производительности - посмотрите в сторону Singleton'а и пакета [Capsule](https://www.google.com/search?q=php%20Capsule).

Comment: Вопрос про DAO. То есть выходит, что если я обращусь в одном контроллере к 10 моделям различными методами (прямые, ajax), то в первый раз создастся подключение и будет сохранено или каждый раз будет создавать новое подключение?

Comment: Ну, DAO ведь тоже относительно высокоуровневая абстракция, и имеет свою реализацию. И в ней можно запросить соединение у какой-либо внешней службы, или инициализировать конструктор DAO уже открытым соединением, или передать ему (DAO) это самое уже открытое соединение каким-либо методом перед первым использованием. Что опять же может привести к использованию одного соединения с БД в одном потоке выполнения. Все зависит от конкретной реализации, которая полностью в Вашей власти. :)
В своем ответе я просто хотел показать несколько возможных подходов к созданию соединений, которые Вам доступны.

Comment: Относительно **если я обращусь в одном контроллере к 10 моделям различными методами (прямые, ajax)**. В ответе я подразумевал обработку HTTP-запроса, т.е. с завершением обработки запроса все ресурсы закрываются автоматически. Обращение по ajax подразумевает запрос другого источника данных на другом хосте либо как минимум создание нового потока исполнения на этом же хосте, который сформирует ответ на запрос ajax. А это уже - другой скрипт, другой поток исполнения, другие соединения с БД, открываемые им для себя. т.е. не входит в область действия моего ответа. :)